# How to transfer my arraylist in a second Activity such that the new Activity holds the ListView instead?

Tags: java, android

My Activity currently holds everything! I would love to have my ListView in another Activity. I have tried cutting and putting in a new Activity, but it can't seem to work because of an error that has to do with the `.setText("")` on the last line.

```
Button save;
ArrayList<String> addArray = new ArrayList<String>();
EditText edit;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailsctivity);

    Intent intent = getIntent();


    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getInput = edit.getText().toString();

            if (addArray.contains(getInput)){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (getInput == null || getInput.trim().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NO ITEM!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                addArray.add(getInput);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DetailsActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        addArray);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.input)).setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The `Intent intent = getIntent();` comes from a button from my MainActivity.
I guess one step of it is to move the array adapter into the new Activity, which I did as well... but failed again. I do understand the usage of intents as well! Maybe something is missing somewhere?

My layout goes like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_detailsctivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.shoppinglist.pixelite.shoppinglist.DetailsActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:hint="@string/newProduct"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below="@id/input"
    >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:hint="@string/add"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could post a short log of the error that you received for us to help you with.

Comment: Can you post the layout file and errors from logcat?

Comment: Are you sure the element with id "input" exists in the layout?

Comment: You don't need to do this `((EditText) findViewById(R.id.input)).setText("")` you already have `edit` .just do `edit.setText("");`

Comment: Alright, let me add my layout file! Anyways! To clarify, the above code works completely fine, just that i wanted the listview to be displayed in another activity instead of this one using the arraylist from the above! How do i do it?